# Use SUMMARIZECOLUMNS on table union in DAX query

Tags: dax

I am trying to write a DAX query that runs the SUMMARIZECOLUMNS function on a table variable. The table variable is the union of two tables that have the same columns in the same order.

When I try to run the query, I get a `Cannot find table` error. Here is the query I am trying to run:

```
EVALUATE
VAR u = UNION(Table1, Table2)
RETURN SUMMARIZECOLUMNS(u[CreationYear], u)
```

How can I run this query on the union of the two tables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not very elegant, but in response to your comment on Marco's solution, you can do a count like this:

```
EVALUATE 
VAR u = UNION(Table1, Table1)
RETURN SUMMARIZE(u, [CreationYear],
           "Count",
           COUNTX(
               FILTER(u,
                   [CreationYear] = EARLIER([CreationYear])
               ),
               [Id]
           )
       )
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using SUMMARIZE in stead of SUMMARIZECOLUMNS. Like this:

```
EVALUATE
VAR u = UNION ( Table1, Table2 ) RETURN SUMMARIZE ( u, [CreationYear] )
```

Comment: Thanks, this does work. However, I am also trying to add a new column where I count the number of rows for each year, like `SUMMARIZE(u, [CreationYear], "Count", COUNT([Id]))`. This gives an error about not being able to identify the table that contains the Id column.